# Syntax in JavaScript- how to summon print function?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am working on a quiz for university.

How can I print the result of the following functions to see the result?

```
var x = 3;
var y = 12;
var z = "Ciao";

var r = y%x;
```

r=?

```
.var r = !(y === x*4);
```

r = ?

```
var r = (x--*6) >= y ? x : z;
```

r = ?

Comment: [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: [output](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp)

Comment: Did you try googling "javascript print"?

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log()` method writes a message to the console, you can use it.

```
var r = (x--*6) >= y ? x : z;
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to print, results will display in console tab of browser

```
console.log(r);
```

with Chrome use F12 to show developer tools, and click to Console tab.